# Can time capsule and airport express utility see my browsing history

Tags: time-capsule, airport

I am a lodger in someone else's house.  They have a time capsule, various airport express base stations and several wifi networks configured.

I am delegated to only use network 1 and I am wondering, can the landlord, using airport express utility see my browsing activity i.e. the actual websites and URLs that I visit?

Comment: They can monitor the traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the programs called Airport Utility have no direct logging or monitoring tools.

That doesn't mean someone that administers your network can't log everything you do (they can since they control the network and can direct your traffic to a tool that will log it), just that the tool to do that directly isn't Airport Utility or the software on Airport routers.

Answer (score 0):

In principle they can since it is the same as a public server.

However, if you are using the HTPPS mode then it will become difficult for them to encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

A general and easy to understand basic answer is if they really wanted to, they could. If not though no, the software alone only allows them to see what you are doing at THAT time but they cannot see your history.